# How to resolve 'Cannot convert from void to WebElement' error in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am getting below error:

**Error:**

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement.
```

**CODE:**

```
WebElement   uploadElement = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='HorizontalLogoPath']"))).click();
uploadElement.sendKeys("D:\\LOGO\\HorizontalLogoPath");
```

And this line of code is part of public void upload() function.

Comment: I am getting error for this line asType mismatch: cannot convert from void to 
  WebElement.And this line of code is part of public void upload() function

Comment: does your upload() function return something?

Answer (score 3):

Method `click()` that you invoke on located element does not return anything. It is **void** (you probably used this "type" in some of your methods declaration like `public static void main()`, etc).

So as that method is called the last in your right-hand side of assignment, Java assumes you're trying to assign what the method returns to what you have on left-hand side.

Hence, type mismatch occurs.

The proper approach would be first assign an element (here it wouldn't be any issue since `findElement()` is called last on the right-hand and it returns `WebElement`)

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement("//input[@id='HorizontalLogoPath']");
```

and then invoke `click()` of your `uploadElement`

Answer (score 2):

First initialize the WebElement and use it further for click or sendkeys() function.

As like below:

```
public void uploadFn()
{
       WebElement   uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='HorizontalLogoPath']"));
       uploadElement.click();
       uploadElement.sendKeys("D:\\LOGO\\HorizontalLogoPath");
}
```